# Word for when proper nouns are whole phrases

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

I've been trying to find a word to describe when things like people's names and place names are whole phrases.
I'm not sure how creditable these are, but I've often seen names in literature like this — especially when used by groups like Native Americans or in fantasy contexts.

In Tui T. Sutherland's book series *Wings of Fire* (specifically in the latest installment, *The Dangerous Gift*), there are multiple villages named like this: Where-the-Terns-Fly, Hamlet-That-Worships-the-Whales-Who-Sing-at-Night, Where-the-Whales-Leap-at-Dawn, and Among-the-Evergreens.

I'd looked into names like these and I did find various other forms of this in places like England (Sutton-under-Whitesontecliffe), France (Germain-de-Tallevende-la-Lande-Vaumont), and Italy (Pino sulla Sponda del Lago Maggiore) (in this case, these are all place-names).

I'm an editor for the *Wings of Fire* Wiki, where we are trying to create a section on an article that describes the naming patterns of the villages within the Ice Kingdom (where these villages are located) — technically, we don't have confirmation that these names actually relate to the village itself. We can just speculate that Among-the-Evergreens is, well, among evergreens; however, speculation isn't allowed on this wiki's article pages. Ergo, the best we can really do is describe the syntax of the village names and not much else.

In total, I'm looking for an adjective that describes these names or a noun that represents these names. Compound words and phrases *are* acceptable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *Hyphenated* proper nouns?

Comment: The section could be called Villages, without commenting on name construction.

Comment: I did not say I "blame" Native Americans for these types of names — that was me stating that a lot of the times *I've* personally seen names like this, it was in that context.

As for the section, it was a decision made by administration that the section should include name patterns due to the fact that the names are unique to the series's world.

Comment: They have these beyond the ocean.  With hyphens, like "Hay-on-Wye" and such village names.  Or "St Martin in the Fields" without hyphens

Comment: I'd looked into names like these and I did find various other forms of this in places like England (Sutton-under-Whitesontecliffe), France (Germain-de-Tallevende-la-Lande-Vaumont), and Italy (Pino sulla Sponda del Lago Maggiore) (in this case, these are all place-names).

Comment: Edited. About your comment stating that that seemed like "cultural (mis)appropriation," that's why I'd said "I'm not sure how creditable these are […]" in the Q.

Comment: Multi-word lexemes are either compounds or metaphors. These are just compound proper nouns, in both the set of compound nouns and the set of proper names. Some are hyphenated, some are open-form. 'Antonomasia' is often involved.

Comment: A [**descriptive toponym**](https://www.worldatlas.com/what-is-a-toponym.html) (or just a **descriptive place name** if you want to avoid the technical word "toponym") is place name that is a description of the place.  This includes examples like your "Where-the-Whales-Leap-at-Dawn", but it's also a broader term that includes short names like "Quebec", which comes from an Ojibwe word meaning "where the river narrows".

Comment: ... and descriptive toponyms are very often also [exonyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endonym_and_exonym)